# Parse.com Database Query browser

Tags: database, user-interface, parse-platform

Is there a way to do general queries on the Parse.com database tables like in standard database clients?

The only way I've done this so far is using my imagination with the SDK in an app and printing out the results. But doing this one their console would be more ideal. Perhaps there is an alternate GUI for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not complete sure what you mean by 'general queries in their console'. But if you mean to find rows based on a conditions then in the Parse.com Dashboard there is a filter icon next to the more button above the table. If you press it, it will open up a dialog for you to be able to enter conditions. However I think it will only allow you to add conditions for the current table.

Comment: but you can't do this between tables? maybe something with the relations section I'm not aware of